# Map two separate arrays by matching object keys to values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Been scratching my head on this one for an entire evening with no solution in sight.

Put simply

I am querying two arrays from two separate APIs.

They return data in following format:

**API 1**

```
[{
  balance: 4444,
  age: "18",
  gender: "Male",
  level: "2",
  name: "Joe"
  
}, {
  balance: 3333,
  age: "45",
  gender: "Male",
  level: "3",
  name: "Angel"
}
}]
```

**API 2**

```
{
  Joe: {
    score: 32
  },
  Angel: {
    score: 22
  }
}
```

I need to match the object keys from the second API to the name value of playerInfo from first API so a new array is made that is completely flat like this:

```
[{
  balance: 4444,
  age: "18",
  gender: "Male",
  level: "2",
  name: "Joe",
  score: 32
  
}, {
  balance: 3333,
  age: "45",
  gender: "Male",
  level: "3",
  name: "Angel",
  score: 22
}
}]
```

Here's where I am being stone walled at the moment

```
var result = []

const matchKeys = (data, data1) => {    
  let arr = []
  arr.push(data1)

  data.map(item => {
    arr.map(item1 => {
      if (item.name === Object.keys(item1)) {
        result.push(Object.assign(item, item1))
        console.log(result)
      }
    })
  })
}

matchKeys(api1, api2)
```

I suspect I'm not getting very far because I am not properly accessing my second dataset because there is no index that keeps track of which object I am supposed to pair up with corresponding value in the arrays.

Appreciate any help

Comment: ```api1.map((item) => ({ ...item, score: api2[item.name].score }));```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement that using `Array.map`.

```js
const input1 = [{
  balance: 4444,
  age: "18",
  gender: "Male",
  level: "2",
  name: "Joe"
}, {
  balance: 3333,
  age: "45",
  gender: "Male",
  level: "3",
  name: "Angel"
}];

const input2 = {
  Joe: {
    score: 32
  },
  Angel: {
    score: 22
  }
}

function matchKeys(arr1, arr2) {
  const result = arr1.map((item) => {
    if (input2[item.name]) {
      return { ...item, ...input2[item.name] };
    }
    return item;
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(matchKeys(input1, input2));
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue I just had to change input2 to arr2

Answer (score 0):

you could use the property of the second object as a way to search the right name.

```js
const input1 = [{
  balance: 4444,
  age: "18",
  gender: "Male",
  level: "2",
  name: "Joe"
}, {
  balance: 3333,
  age: "45",
  gender: "Male",
  level: "3",
  name: "Angel"
}];

const input2 = {
  Joe: {
    score: 32
  },
  Angel: {
    score: 22
  }
}

const matchKeys = (data, data1) => {
  return data.map((item) => ({ ...item, score: data1[item.name] ? data1[item.name].score : 0 }));
}

console.log(matchKeys(input1, input2));
```

also checked if it has a name and if for some reason it didn't I inserted a default score.